# SignalR: Persistent Connection Example in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr

I've tried to rebuild the [C# Persistent Connection Example](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection) I found on Github in VB.net but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have done:

### 1) Creating a new Endpoint in a new VB Class

```
Imports SignalR

Imports System.Threading.Tasks


Public Class MyEndPoint

Inherits PersistentConnection

Protected Overrides Function OnConnectedAsync(request As IRequest, connectionId As   String) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Return Connection.Broadcast("Connection " + connectionId + " connected")

End Function


End Class
```

### 2) Add routing into global.asax file

```
Public Class Global_asax
Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection(Of MyEndPoint)("echo", "echo/{*operation}")

End Sub

End Class
```

I've got the following debug information:

> Extension method 'Public Function MapConnection(name As String, url As String, type As System.Type) As System.Web.Routing.RouteBase' defined in 'SignalR.RouteExtensions' is not generic (or has no free type parameters) and so cannot have type arguments.

Any idea how I can rewrite this line of code to get it working?

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection(Of MyEndPoint)("echo", "echo/{*operation}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the code to work by using the non-generic overload of the MapConnection extension method:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection("echo", "echo/{*operation}", GetType(MyEndpoint))
```

Hopefully that will get you going.

Comment: Hi, it worked! Thx a million, I got headache from this stuff. :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that helped. Though I do hope someone can come by and explain why the generic methods apparently don't work in VB.Net.